# Create a vector based on another vector in R?

Tags: r

In my data I have a vector of characters, where one of the characters (in this case, the letter `P`) is repeated a certain number of times. For example, if I have the following information:

```
number <- 2
iterations <- 2
```

and a vector of characters:

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("P", "a", "b", "P", "d", "a", "k",
                         "P", "e", "q", "s", "P", "d", "v", "i", "j"))
```

We can see that `P` is repeated 4 times. Or, to put it another way, `P` is repeated `number * iterations` times.

So in my code, I have some function that creates the data frame `df`, it will create a sequence of strings that always start with `P`. This happens `number` of times (in this example 2)... and gets iterated by the `iterations` number (in this example, also, 2). So that means `P` appears `number * iterations` times in my data frame.

Im trying to create a new column that will contain the iteration number. So, in my example, the first two `P`'s would be in iteration 1 and the second two would be in iteration 2. For example, my desired output would look something like:

```
> df
   var iter
1    P    1
2    a    1
3    b    1
4    P    1
5    d    1
6    a    1
7    k    1
8    P    2
9    e    2
10   q    2
11   s    2
12   P    2
13   d    2
14   v    2
15   i    2
16   j    2
```

I hope what I said makes sense... I was finding it difficult to accurately word this problem

Comment: I posted a solution based on the column value of occurence of 'P' instead of having to rely on another vector

Comment: `(cumsum(df$var == "P") + 1) %/% 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `gl` to do this - `replace` a vector of `NA`s where the 'var' is 'P' with the `gl` indexing and then use `fill` to replace the `NA` with the non-NA previous value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(iter = replace(rep(NA_integer_, n()), var == 'P', 
     as.integer(gl(sum(var == 'P'), 2, sum(var == 'P'))))) %>% 
     fill(iter)
```

-output

```
   var iter
1    P    1
2    a    1
3    b    1
4    P    1
5    d    1
6    a    1
7    k    1
8    P    2
9    e    2
10   q    2
11   s    2
12   P    2
13   d    2
14   v    2
15   i    2
16   j    2
```